# Safest way to wipe sensitive information off company phone before giving it away

Tags: mobile, deletion

We have a lot of devices in my company that we use to test and after some years some of them become unsupported.
We are thinking about selling some of the ones that are not used any more but worry that there might be recoverable leftovers of sensitive information in them.

What would be the best way to be sure that no one will be able to recover any past sensitive information from the phone? (we have Android and iOS devices)

Comment: Modern smartphones have encryption by default. Factory reset is enough to clear encryption keys from the secure hardware and the storage is also wiped.